# Query append only table; distinct inner join issue

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, stitch

I have the following SQL that attempts to grab the latest version of every row in a results table, i.e a singular row that has a unique confirmation_number, the max seq and max batch, this is using append-only replication [(docs)](https://www.stitchdata.com/docs/data-structure/querying-append-only-tables#latest-version-every-row). However it is faulty returning no results, the inner join works as expected but not the outter. Expected result

```
confirmation_number |  date | seq     | batch
23742902            |  date | max(seq)| max(batch)
```

```
  SELECT DISTINCT r.*
    FROM `results_table` r
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT confirmation_number,
      date,
      MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
      MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch
      FROM `results_table`
      GROUP BY confirmation_number, date) rr
    ON r.confirmation_number = rr.confirmation_number 
    AND r.date = rr.date
    AND r._sdc_sequence = rr.seq
    AND r._sdc_batched_at = rr.batch
```

This is the table I want to query against, and my sql is returning no result set. It should return me a singular row that contains a distinct confirmation_number, max seq and max batch

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you get back _no_ results, or you do get results, but they aren't what you were expecting?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am getting no results for rows that should be returning a singular record that contains a unique confirmation_number, max seq and max batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I am quite guessing here about your expected result - but below looks to me should give you expected

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(r ORDER BY seq DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.results_table` r
GROUP BY confirmation_number
```

As you can see here - it returns one row per confirmation_number - the row which has max seq value for that confirmation_number with all respective values (date, batch, etc.)

Not sure if you need to group also by `date` (as it is in the query in your question - but in my mind it is not needed) - but if you do need  - it is easy to add

Comment: per you recent edit - looks like my above answer is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: the only issue I see is if there is a max seq and max batch in different records, how would I return only one row?

Comment: @Squirtle - that is even much simpler - but what would be the logic for `date` field? where the date value should come from? please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one max seq or batch then u get result if you use both then not possible to get record because of possible both max value is return from different row's so... May use like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
    FROM `results_table` r
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT confirmation_number,
      date,
      MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
      MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch
      FROM `results_table`
      GROUP BY confirmation_number, date) rr
    ON r.confirmation_number = rr.confirmation_number 
    AND r.date = rr.date
    AND r._sdc_sequence = rr.seq
    ----AND r._sdc_batched_at = rr.batch
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
    FROM `results_table` r
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT confirmation_number,
      date,
      MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
      MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch
      FROM `results_table`
      GROUP BY confirmation_number, date) rr
    ON r.confirmation_number = rr.confirmation_number 
    AND r.date = rr.date
    ----AND r._sdc_sequence = rr.seq
    AND r._sdc_batched_at = rr.batch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain every row in the original table, on the left side of the join, then you should remove the restrictions on the max from the join conditions:

```
SELECT r.*, rr.seq, rr.batch
FROM results_table r
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT confirmation_number, date, MAX(_sdc_sequence) AS seq,
           MAX(_sdc_batched_at) AS batch
    FROM results_table
    GROUP BY confirmation_number, date
) rr
    ON r.confirmation_number = rr.confirmation_number AND
       r.date = rr.date;
```

The logic of the query is simply to bring in the maximum `_sdc_sequence` and `_sdc_batched_at` values for each confirmation number/date group, along with the columns that already are there in your table.

Comment: I have updated my example table for more clearer explination

Comment: Bad news: It isn't any clearer.  But if you can comment on my answer, we can at least confirm/rule out one possible interpretation of your problem.